# Getting secret from Azure key vault

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-keyvault, secret-key

I'm trying to get secret from azure key vault.

So i found the code below but got an error.

```
AppServiceMSICredentials credentials = new AppServiceMSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(credentials);

String secret =  keyVaultClient.getSecret("uri", "secretName").value();
```

I got an error like this:

```
Error >>> endpoint == null
```

I also tried this way:

```
AppServiceMSICredentials credentials = new AppServiceMSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE, "MSI Url????", "secret???");
KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(credentials);

String secret =  keyVaultClient.getSecret("keyVault Uri", "secret name").value(); 

log.debug("secret=========",secret);
```

I'm new to Azure and now i cannot find the solutions....

How can i solve it?
Also how can i find msi endpoint and secret??

Thank you.

Comment: what is uri? check the value.

Comment: @MaheshKava I did this way -->>  "https://<myAzure>.vault.azure.net/"

Answer (score 1):

You were using [managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview). You do not need to provide any endpoint or secret.

The only thing you need to do is to [enable system identity in your web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?context=azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/context/msi-context).

After that, you will get an object id of a service principal. then you can assign access policy in your key vault for that  service principal.

Finally, you can access your key vault and secret in your spring boot application.

---

**Update:**

If you cannot create managed identity, then you can get an access token with Azure AD library. And then use that token to access key vault.

Here is a code sample:

```
public class KeyVaultTest {

    // Add access policy to user, and access key vault as user
    private static AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenAsUser(String authorization, String resource) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, MalformedURLException {

        String clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2";
        String username = "your user id, jack@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com";
        String password = "your password,  ********";
        AuthenticationResult result = null;

        //Starts a service to fetch access token.
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authorization, false, service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(resource, clientId, username, password, null);
            result = future.get();
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }

        if (result == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Authentication results were null.");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String vaultBase = "https://keyvault279.vault.azure.net/";

        KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultCredentials(){
            @Override
            public String doAuthenticate(String authorization, String resource, String scope) {
                String token = null;
                try {
                    AuthenticationResult authResult = getAccessTokenAsUser(authorization, resource);
                    token = authResult.getAccessToken();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return token;
            }
        });

        SecretBundle test = keyVaultClient.getSecret(vaultBase, "test");
        System.out.println(test.value());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, i found out that i cannot use managed identity. I don't have authority. Is there any other way that i can get secret from key vault??? Thank you so much.