# Retrieve secret Azure vault AAD auth

Tags: java, azure

This regarding Azure vault. Please help me know how to retrieve data from azure vault using java.
I have tried most of the options available in the internet but have not received any descriptions or detail as to what is happening in the code.
I am new to coding hence it is a little difficult to understand .

**UPDATE**
I used the code mentioned in below reference but i am unable to write the same program for spring boot. I am how shold i convert this to restcontroller

Below are ref i used :[How can i get secret from key vault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57765760/how-can-i-get-secret-from-key-vault/60333138#60333138)

Comment: Could you add code snippets of some code you tried in the question?

Comment: If you want to know how to retrieve a secret from Azure key vault, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Just follow the steps of my answer in [How can i get secret from key vault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766204/10223674) to register an application and add access policy to it in Azure KeyVault.
2. Get my sample at [AzureKeyVault](https://github.com/AI-EVO/AzureKeyVault)

In my sample, I just create an utils class and then use it in controllers to access KeyVault. To, run the sample, you need to change the environment variables' values in `application.properties` to your own values.

[image]